# heroku error in db:push

Tags: heroku

I am trying to push MYSQL schema to my app which has clearDB addon. Getting this error message when i run herko db:push mysql.....

Can any one help me to identify the issue. Thanks for your time in advance.

================================

Sending schema
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/schema:3
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:07
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/schema:3:in`require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/schema:3
 !    Heroku client internal error..
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       unexpected nil (OkJson::ParserError)
Backtrace:   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/vendor/okjson.rb:82:in `valparse'
```

Comment: Looks like i might not be able to push the schemas via the db push.[link] http://news361.org/heroku-db-push-missing-sequel-gem.html [link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `heroku db:push` with none Heroku databases. Best way is to dump your database and then restore directly into your ClearDB instance.